# Making a blog in JRuby

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails

I have made blog using ruby on rails, and it's pretty easy. What i am trying to do is that there is a website code written in Java, and I want to add this blog into that site. It's really easy making that blog into ruby on rails. The challenging part is to add this blog to the site, cause site is written in Java. do you think JRuby on rails is the answer to this? I am new to JRuby on Rails. Does anyone know a good book to start learning JRuby on Rails from scratch?

Thanks a lot for your time ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ruby on Rails portion will be exactly the same - except in this case you can package the site into a .war file and integrate that into your Java Application Server.

At the JRuby wiki site, you'll fine a large amount of links all about how to do this depending on what your hosting software is.

http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/JRubyOnRails